# How can I copy the html from one node to another programmatically?

Tags: nodes, javascript

I have an angular app running in a drupal page. The app goes out and fetches item data from an API, and displays the formatted item data in the drupal page.

I have no way of searching the data returned by the angular app -- as far as drupal is concerned, the page is blank.

Is there a way to copy the html created by the angular app, from the page where it resides, to another page as raw html? That should make it visible to drupal.

Comment: Angular is JavaScript based, so without some smart parsing of data Drupal will not be able to see the content. (How to do this is out of the scope of this site and is better asked on stackoverflow.com) But fetching data through 3 different layers is not going to make it easy. You might have more luck loading the data directly into Drupal, as Joseph suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to copy the html created by the angular app, from the page where it resides, to another page as raw html? That should make it visible to drupal.

You're approaching the problem from the wrong angle. The root of the problem is that Drupal does not have the data supplied by the API, and NOT because Drupal does not have the HTML from Angular. Consider syncing Drupal with your API endpoint instead.

One route is to use the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module, together with [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) for pre-processing and [Feeds Ex](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex) to allow various data formats. Another approach is to use the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module.